# HTML textarea to javascript and keep line break

Tags: javascript, textarea, line-breaks

I am trying to pass a HTML `<textarea>` through JavaScript, and want to keep the line breaks. Ex when I write:

```
Line a
Line b
```

It comes out as:

```
Line a Line b
```

My code:

```js
function textwrite(){
  thetext = document.getElementById("text_change").value;    
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = thetext;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='text_change' oninput='textwrite()'></textarea>
    
<p id="demo"></p>
```

And I don't want to use `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to add line breaks to an HTML textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/javascript-how-to-add-line-breaks-to-an-html-textarea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve line breaks in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593103/preserve-line-breaks-in-textarea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `\n`,`\r`,`\n\r` with `</br>` in java script:

```
var myLineBreak = thetext.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"</br>");
```

```js
function textwrite(){
     thetext = document.getElementById("text_change").value;  
      var myLineBreak = thetext.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"</br>");

     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myLineBreak;
    }
```

```html
<textarea id='text_change' oninput='textwrite()'></textarea>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> The `white-space` CSS property sets how white space inside an element is handled.

with value `pre-wrap` where

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```js
function textwrite(){
  thetext = document.getElementById("text_change").value;    
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = thetext;
}
```

```css
#demo { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

```html
<textarea id='text_change' oninput='textwrite()'></textarea>
    
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Want to add some comments that explain why this solves the problem?

Comment: @RyanWilson, updated the answer with some documentation....hope that makes more sense now......thanks

Comment: Thank you, that is much better. +1 from me.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the string saves those line breaks itself, but you have to specify the CSS to show it, thx!

Answer (score 0):

To do that, first set the multiline property of the textBox to true and then include at the end of each line this: `"\r\n"`