# How to copy the value of the textarea as it is (with \n and all this stuff)?

Tags: javascript, laravel, ace-editor

I have the following laravel form and I want to copy the text from the code editor as it were wrote:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor {
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        right: 150px;
        bottom: 150px;
        left: 150px;
    }
  .ace_editor {
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        margin: auto;
        height: 65%;
        width: 55%;
    }
    .scrollmargin {
        height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    }
</style>

{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProblemsController@store']) !!}
  <div id="editor"></div>
  <input type="textarea" name="codeSrc" id="codeSrc" style="display: none;">
  {{Form::submit('Submit')}}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/c_cpp");
    //here I am taking the text from the hidden textarea
    editor.session.on('change', function(delta) {
      var content=document.getElementById('hiddenInput');
      content.value=editor.getValue();
    });
</script>
```

I want to take the text input as it is, like that:

```
// Your First C++ Program

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Not in a single line like that, the \n is just ignored `// Your First C++ Program#include int main() {std::cout << "Hello World!";return 0;}`
Even the `<iostream>` got disappeared because it is interpreted as an html tag. The point of this is to transfer it to an .cpp file and execute it, so I want it as it is, not modified.

Comment: Wait... how is the C++ you've included related to the problem?

Comment: ? How it isn't? It is an example where I show that I want to copy the text like it was wrote between ```those stuff```, not all of it in a single line. When I sav, the next lines (\n) are just ignored. I also edited the question

Comment: I understand. In that case, you could better use some dummy text like "Lorem ipsum etc.etc.", because the C++ text gives the impression that this source code is part of your application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserve line breaks in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593103/preserve-line-breaks-in-textarea)

Comment: What “textarea” are you even talking about? `<input type="textarea">` does not exist in HTML. Unless this is something Laravel is supposed to automatically transform into an actual `textarea` _element_ somehow (doubt it), you are probably loosing your line breaks by using the wrong type of element to begin with (browsers will treat this as `type="text"`)

Comment: Did you try to find a similar question here on stackoverflow? This is an important step to take before you post a question. Please search for 'preserve line breaks in textarea' and see if that gives a solution for your problem.

Comment: @CBroe Please do not use comments to post an answer. Answers should be posted as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I usually comment first, until I _know_ that something is definitively the answer to the question. So far, I think this is still more in the clarification phase.

Comment: @CBroe I changed from text to text area but is the same thing

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I tried your solution too but it doesn't work for me

Comment: So where do things actually start to go wrong? What have your debugging attempts regarding this resulted in so far? Did you start with a simply console.log of the value you are reading with `editor.getValue`, to verify that even still contains what you think it should? What are the further processing steps after this?

Comment: @CBroe So I did this: changed the input type to text, add the input type a class in css with ```white-space: pre-line;```, after that the text were passed to my controller and saved as JSON. I saved the JSON text to a string like that ```$codeSrc = $request['codeSrc]``` and then saved the string into a new .txt file with this laravel function ```File::put('path\textt.txt', $codeSrc);``` . The text is saved but in a single line

Comment: Simple text fields are not made to transport values with line breaks, and any formatting using `white-space` or similar affects _display_ only to begin with. Use a _proper_ hidden field, or an actual textarea. Also, why no feedback on the absolutely _basic_ debugging steps I asked you to perform? Have you, or have you not, _verified_ that the value you are trying to stuff into the field, contains the data including line breaks as you expected it to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215173/discussion-between-alex-unlimited-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. So:

The `editor.getValue()` should be replaced with `editor.getSession.getValue()` and it will return the text as it was write (with new lines). The `content.value` on the other hand it will return the single line text, so we need to change from this:

```
editor.session.on('change', function(delta) {
   var content=document.getElementById('hiddenInput');
   content.value=editor.getValue();
});
```

to this:

```
editor.session.setNewLineMode("auto");
editor.getSession().on("change", function () {
   document.getElementById('codeSrc').value = 
   editor.getSession().getValue().replace(/\r\n|\n|\r/g, '<br/>');
   console.log(editor.getSession().getValue());
});
```

That's all.