# HTML/PHP entering multiline input and I am hetting it in single line. How to solve it?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making a form in html
and there is a `<textarea>` tag in that form.
first.php is like:

```
<form method="post" action="next.php">
    <textarea name="desc" raws="4">Here, Its Text Area</textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">NEXT BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

And next.php is like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{   
    $desc = $_POST["desc"];

    echo $desc; //<------ ECHO LINE 1
}
else
{
    header("location: first.php");
    
}
```

And when I am typing this message:

```
Hi,
Helo there,
I am LakshyaK2011.
```

And echoing in it next.php, in echo line 1 (See In next.php's code)
It is displaying like this:

`Hi, Helo there, I am LakshyaK2011.`

is there any fixes to it?
Thanks,

I have tried:
(I didn't know what to do so I tried nothing)

I have expected:
I will enter:

```
Hi,
Helo there,
I am LakshyaK2011.
```

And it will print same as that.
Not like:
`Hi, Helo there, I am LakshyaK2011.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserve line breaks in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593103/preserve-line-breaks-in-textarea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display **new line** in HTML format, you need something such as `<br>`

So Change

```
 echo $desc;
```

to

```
 echo str_replace(chr(13), '<br>',$desc);
```

**Alternatively**, use `nl2br()`

https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Thanks, It Worked,
I Did Know About str_replace()
But I Didnt Know What Is Next Line(ENTER) Character Is Called.

Comment: There's a built-in `nl2br()` function for this.

Comment: Ok I will definetly try it.